# Rails creates routes from objects

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, routes, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a routes file that looks something like this (It's very deeply nested...I know):

```
  scope :admin, module: :admin do
    namespace :breadth do
      resources :areas, as: 'areas' do
        resources :sequences, as: 'sequences'
      end
    end
  end
```

When running `rake routes` I get a back all of the routes including one called `breatdh_area_sequences` (which is exactly what I want). The problem is that when I create a form rails builds up the wrong url based on the parameters I'm giving it:

```
= form_for [:breadth, breadth_sequence.area, breadth_sequence] do |f|
  ...
```

This gives me:

```
undefined method `breadth_breadth_area_breadth_sequences_path' for #<#<Class:0x007fe55bcf16b8>:0x007fe55d9a3f68>
```

Exactly how does rails take this array of parameters and create a URL path out of it? I'm assuming it calls a method on each object? Is this something I can override in order to get the named route I'm expecting (not overriding :url on form_for)

Comment: you can just try "form_for breadth_area_sequences_path"

Comment: I could but depending on whether `breadth_sequence` is a new record or not, this URL will change (`breadth_area_sequence_path` for existing records and `breadth_area_sequences_path` for new objects). I would like rails to figure this out on its own without me specifying the URL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to make this work I had to override the `self.model_name` methods on both `BreadthArea` and `BreadthSequence`. This method is how `form_for` figures out the URL when an object (or an array of objects) is used at the first argument.

```
class BreadthArea < ActiveRecord::Base
  def self.model_name
    ActiveModel::Name.new(self, nil, "Area")
  end
  ...
end

class BreadthSequence < ActiveRecord::Base
  def self.model_name
    ActiveModel::Name.new(self, nil, "Sequence")
  end
  ...
end
```

Comment: Changing something so widely used as model name could have other implications on your codebase, I wouldn't recommend doing that, a lot of code relies on that information.

Answer (score 0):

Since you want to name your objects differently from the routes, it won't work. Your routes/controllers need to be named just as your models are named, if your model is `BreadthArea` (as the route believes it is) your route should also be named in the same way.

Comment: This isn't exactly the case. See my solution (not the most elegant but definitely works).